# Isosceles has maximum vertex angle between triangles of equal area

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to prove the following that in the image below (E1 & E2 are parallel, AB=AC) no matter where I move the vertex point A on line E1 (keeping BC as is), the vertex angle A is going to decrease (i.e. the vertex angle is max when AB=BC for triangles of equal base, height and area). I tried using areas and the law of sines but I can't get to a formula dependent on angles, any hints? Thanks! [image: Equal area triangles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a circle through ABC.  Let D be the intersection of BA' with the circle.  You may know that $\angle BDC = \angle BAC$.  A' is outside the circle, so $\angle BA'C$ is smaller.

Comment: Hi Michael and many thanks for your answer...only I'm not sure I follow...my triangle is isosceles, not equilateral (height not equal to BC). How can I draw a circle through its vertices?

Comment: Let F be the midpoint of BA.  Draw a line through F, perpendicular to BA.  It will cut AM at a point N.  This point is equidistant from A and B, because it is on FN, and is also equidistant from B and C because it is on AM.  It is the same distance from all three points, so a circle centred at N will go through all three of A,B,C.  It is called the circumcircle of ABC, and all triangles have one.

Comment: Excellent! Beautiful proof, thank you!